# here.com API about time windows and future visits

Tags: here-api, here-tourplanning

I'm looking at the documentation of here.com API and I'm unable to find answer to this.

Is it possible to have tours planned in such a way that the tour can span more days?

For example I have meeting *already planned* in a given place two days from now.

I want to submit a request that takes into consideration this visit that will happen in two days, so to propose to reach a nearby place on that date, instead of today.

Is it possible to have this behviour with here APIs?

Answer (score 0):

We have tried to understand your request, however at the moment HERE only has  two APIs for it:

```
1.  Waypoints Sequence: https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-waypoints/dev_guide/index.html
2.  Tour Planning: https://developer.here.com/documentation/tour-planning/2.3.0/dev_guide/index.html
```